# ajax send a value in url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am facing problem with send another value in data

```
data:'id='+id+'&action='+action+'&a=+abc',
```

like this.
here **abc is a php variable in hidden input type** to be send on add-like-tj.php

please try to fix this code. i don't have good understanding of ajax i am new to use this.

```js
function addLikes(id,action) {
 $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').each(function(index) {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('#tutorial-'+id+' #rating').val((index+1));
  if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').index(obj)) {
   return false; 
  }
 });
 $.ajax({
 url: "add-like-tj.php",
 data:'id='+id+'&action='+action,
 type: "POST",
 beforeSend: function(){
  $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='loaderIcon.gif' />");
 },
 success: function(data){
 var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+id).val());
 switch(action) {
  case "like":
  $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'unlike\')" />');
  likes = likes+1;
  break;
  case "unlike":
  $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'like\')" />')
  likes = likes-1;
  break;
 }
 $('#likes-'+id).val(likes);
 if(likes>0) {
  $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
 } else {
  $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html('');
 }
 }
 });
}
```

```css
.demo-table .highlight, .demo-table .selected {color:#F4B30A;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #F48F0A;}
.btn-likes {float:left; padding: 0px 5px;cursor:pointer;}
.btn-likes input[type="button"]{width:20px;height:20px;border:0;cursor:pointer;}
.label-likes {font-size:12px;color:#2F529B;height:20px;}
.desc {clear:both;color:#999;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tutorial-63">
<input type="hidden" id="likes-63" value="9">
<div class="btn-likes">
<input type="button" title="Like" class="like" onclick="addLikes(63,'like')"></div>
<div class="label-likes">9 Like(s)</div>
</div>
```

this is the codes i am using.

Comment: `data:'id='+id+'&action='+action+'&a='+$('#likes-63').val()`

Comment: data:{id:id,action:action,a:abc}

Comment: @jcubic `+encodeURIComponent($('#likes-63').val())` might be safer ; )

Comment: A better way of sending data with jQuery AJAX is using object: `data: {foo: data1, bar: data2}`

Comment: if you want to send data via url you should use type:GET , instead of type:POST

Comment: Are you using the `$_GET` array or the `$_POST` array in your PHP script `add-like-tj.php`

Comment: i am using $_POST. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2):

create an object of key/value pairs...

```
data:{id:id, action:action},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like following instead.

```
data:{id:id, action: action, a: 'abc'}
```

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this
  data: { field1: variable1, field2 :variable2} ,

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your function to

```
    function addLikes(id,action) {
    $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' #rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
    url: "add-like-tj.php",
    data:{id:id, action: action, a: 'abc'},
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='loaderIcon.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(data){
    var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+id).val());
    switch(action) {
        case "like":
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'unlike\')" />');
        likes = likes+1;
        break;
        case "unlike":
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'like\')" />')
        likes = likes-1;
        break;
    }
    $('#likes-'+id).val(likes);
    if(likes>0) {
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
    } else {
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html('');
    }
    }
    });
}
```

Then in your php file `(add-like-tj.php)` , you can receive your data using `POST METHOD` such as

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
$a = $_POST['abc'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
 $.ajax({
url: "add-like-tj.php",
data:{id:id, action: action, a: 'abc'},
type: "POST",
beforeSend: function(){
    $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='loaderIcon.gif' />");
}
```

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.